# How do I resolve the following error in my bit shifting C code?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

Can anyone help me with the below? Say I have the binary value `int colour` which is 255 or i.e.

```
00000000 00000000 000000000 11111111
```

in binary. How can I perform shifting to get

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000
```

I tried making 4 values of `0xff`, `0xff00`, `0xff0000`, `0xff000000` and was going to OR them but when I print these values out I get the following error:

```
converter.c:66:23: runtime error: left shift of 255 by 24 places cannot be represented in type 'int'
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior converter.c:66:23 

in 
VALS ARE ff,  ff00, ff0000, ff000000
```

Below is my code any help would be greatly appreciated

```c
  int val1 = colour;
  int val2 = (colour << 8);
  int val3 = (colour << 16);
  int val4 = (colour << 24);
  //unsigned int val5 = 0;
  printf("VALS ARE %x,  %x, %x, %x\n" , val1, val2, val3, val4);
  //rowElement(colour, sketch);
```

Comment: Try with `unsigned int` types.

Comment: In your own words: What is the result of `255 << 24`?  Why should that result fit in the `int` type? Is `int` actually the type you want? Do you know what `signed` and `unsigned` mean? Do you see how they might be relevant to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error because you're shifting a value into the sign bit of an `int`.  If you shift a 1 into that bit, you trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This is described in section 6.5.7p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding bitwise shift operators:

> The  result  of **E1 << E2** is **E1** left-shifted **E2** bit  positions;
> vacated  bits  are  filled  with zeros. If **E1** has  an  unsigned  type,
> the  value  of  the  result  is **E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>**, reduced  modulo one  more
> than  the  maximum  value  representable  in  the  result  type. If **E1**
> has  a  signed type  and  nonnegative  value,  and **E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>** is
> representable  in  the  result  type,  then  that  is the resulting
> value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Change the type of each of your variables to `unsigned int`.  Then you can freely shift into any of the bits, as long as you don't shift by 32 bits or more, assuming an `int` is 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to write

```
int x = 255;
x ~= x;
```

Or it will be better to declare the variable x as having the type unsigned int.

```
unsigned int x = 255;
x ~= x;
```

As for the shift operator then according to the C Standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 4 The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
> bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
> the result is E1 × 2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
> representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed type and
> nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type,
> then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
> undefined.**

Comment: Still better work with `unsigned`

Comment: @EugeneSh. However according ti the C Standard this operation is allowed for objects of the type int.

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the bytes in `ARGB` color or any 32-bit unsigned integer, shift to the right, then AND with `0xff` For example, to get `44` from `0x11223344` we need just `0x11223344 & 0xff` To get `33`, shift right by 8 bits -> `0x00112233` and then AND with `0xff` again.

Left-shift is needed to build a 32-bit integer again.

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int colour = 0x11223344;

    unsigned char byte0, byte1, byte2, byte3;
    byte0 = (colour      ) & 0xff;
    byte1 = (colour >> 8 ) & 0xff;
    byte2 = (colour >> 16) & 0xff;
    byte3 = (colour >> 24) & 0xff;

    unsigned int reversed = byte0 << 24 | byte1 << 16 | byte2 << 8 | byte3;

    printf("%08X\n", colour);
    printf("%08X\n", reversed);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
11223344
44332211
```